# vba delete excel column when entire column data is "Null"

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyOyC.jpg)I am trying to create a vba which will check if a column has all the values as "Null" (String value) not empty or blank, If it has "Null" String value it will delete the entire column.
I can use for loop to loop through all the values in cells, but it istime consuming. I am looking for an option to use AutoFilter or Find command.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
Dim col as Range
For Each col In UsedRange.Columns
    If col.Find("*") Is Nothing Then
        col.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next
```

**Update**

I don't think you can have "Null" cell values in Excel. I tried this

```
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = Range("A1")
cell.Value = ""       ' cell.Value2 shows as "Empty" in the Locals window
cell.Value = Empty    ' cell.Value2 still "Empty"
cell.Value = Nothing  ' this gives "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined Error"
```

**Update 2**

Another slower way can be to find all blank cells in the column

```
Dim col as Range, blanks as Range
For Each col In UsedRange.Columns
    Set blanks = col.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) ' gives error if no blank cells in the col range
    If blanks.Cells.Count = col.Cells.Count Then
        col.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next
```

**Update 3**

You can use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(col, "Null")` to count the number of "Null" cells

```
Dim col As Range
For Each col In UsedRange.Columns
    'NullCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(col, "Null")
    'NotNullCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(col, "<>Null")
    'blanksCount = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(col)
    'nonBlanksCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(col)
    With WorksheetFunction
        If .CountA(col) = .CountIf(col, "Null") + 1 Then  ' 1 for the column header cell
            col.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Slai, thanks for you answer. but i am not sure the above code will  find if  all the cell's in the column contains "Null" String.Please note I am not checking for Null value . Its "Null" String. Sorry if i missed this on my question.

Comment: Is there anyway that i can use Find,search,match command for <> (search string) . So that i can search for something like "<>Null" in column and delete if not found.

Comment: Not really. You can Home > Find & Select > Constants or Formulas

Comment: I need to be done in VBA , since it is an automation tool. Also , please consider the cell value as String type "Null" not the datatype. Refer my Image attached in question. In the image Column 'B' has to be removed.Because it has all the cell value as "Null".

Comment: I just saw the image and now I am not sure why my answer is accepted even that I misunderstood the question. I will try to think of another answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the worksheet, the formula:

```
=COUNTBLANK(A:A)
```

will return 1048576 if all the cells in that column are either *NULL* or totally empty.  We can take advantage of this in the macro:

```
Sub KolumnKiller()
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            If .CountBlank(Columns(i)) <> Rows.Count Then Exit For
        Next i

        For j = i To 1 Step -1
            If .CountBlank(Columns(j)) = Rows.Count Then
                Columns(j).Delete
            End If
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

The first loop finds a good starting place for the second loop.